# UML representation of PHP trait

Tags: php, symfony, uml, behavior, traits

I'm creating projects with Symfony2/Doctrine and try to implement traits.
So far no problem on small tryouts, but I usually do UML class and sequence diagrams before deep in complex projects.

What is the UML design object(s) to be used to symbolize PHP traits, which can be seen as far as I know as behaviors? Is ther any clean way to do so?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Nicolas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PHP` `Trait` is basically [UML Abstract Class](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html#abstract-class) or [UML Class Template](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html#class-template) connected to the used-in class with the [UML Generalization Relationship](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) utilizing the **multiple inheritance** notation

[image]

See also:

- Figure "UML Diagram with a Trait" in article [Brendan Bates: Traits: The Right Way](http://brendan-bates.com/traits-the-right-way/)
- [Programmers: Is there a representation for mixins or traits on UML?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215968/is-there-a-representation-for-mixins-or-traits-on-uml)
- > [PHP Manual → Language Reference → Classes and Objects → Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)
  >
  > As of `PHP` 5.4.0, `PHP` implements a method of **code reuse** called `Traits`.
  >
  > `Traits` are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as `PHP`. A `Trait` is intended to **reduce some limitations of single inheritance** by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of `Traits` and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance and `Mixins`.
  >
  > A `Trait` is similar to a class, but only intended to group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is **not possible to instantiate** a `Trait` on its own. It is an addition to traditional inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is, the application of class members without requiring inheritance

Comment: You're right, I juste forgot the fact that single inheritance is PHP implementation choice. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In the earliest paper that I've seen Roles/Traits explained, they are represented in UML with a line connecting the Role/Trait to the method/function inside the class. http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf