# How to depict in a UML class diagram that a method accept multiple types?

Tags: php, uml

I'm working on a PHP project and I'm doing its UML documentation. 
I need to specify that a method accept multiple data types and I can't figure out how to do it.

For instance:
I want to represent a PHP class called 'A' in a UML class diagram:

```
<?php 

    class A{ 
        private $_data;  

        public function __construct() { 
            $this->_data = array(); 
        } 

        public function add( $key , $value){ 
            $this->_data[$key] = $value; 
        }                        
    } 

    $oA = new A(); 
    $oA->add( 1, 'John Doe' ); // key is an int and value is a string 
    $oA->add( "Fruits" , array("Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi") ); // string, array 
    $oA->add( "pi", 3.1415 ); 
    //and so on...       
?>
```

Note that add() function can receive keys and values of different kind of data. So, I can't specify in my UML class diagram something like “key:integer” or “value : string[]” because their data type can change depending on what kind of data is passed when the method is called.

Is there a way to depict this fact in UML notation?

Can I specify something like:

```
+ add( key:mixed , value:mixed)
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: UML Operation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html)
- [Stack Overflow: UML representation of PHP trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882903/uml-representation-of-php-trait)

Comment: Technically, String and Number are not classes in PHP. Should I add an stereotype like <<datatype>> in those classes?

Comment: @EmilianoSangoi in my opinion it depends on the level of detail needed (who will read the documentation and why). You can use/model language-agnostic high level concepts or drop down to low level details like [phpDocumentor > Types > Primitives](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#primitives). Why would your diagram's reader need to know about `<<datatype>>`? Wouldn't the corresponding `database` data type be more useful?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem with interpreting languages and I guess there is nothing off-the-shelf you can get here. One possible way would be to declare the parameter being of the (abstract) class `Varying` (or whatever you'd like to call it). That could simply be a convention in your model where you describe at a global place that such a type means that the method accepts varying parameters. So your `add` would appear as

```
+ add(Varying)
```

You could (theoretically) introduce a formally correct way for such parameters. But that's not worth the effort (except you'll do that in some UML class at university).

**Edit** Alternatively it is possible to use tagged values to make model readers aware of such constructs. Depending on the tool those tagged values can control visible representation as well as code generation.

Comment: Is it possible use "tagged values"?, for instance like "{isMixed=true}" or sth similar? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. That's always a way to make your model aware of such things. As said: there is no standard for doing it. If you happen to use Enterprise Architect then tagged values allow to react on this on code generation.