# How to model traits in StarUML?

Tags: uml, traits, staruml

I recently found the concept of `traits` and would like to implement them into my `StarUML`-diagram, but I did not found a class for `Traits` in the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML representation of PHP trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882903/uml-representation-of-php-trait)